# Как сделать так, чтобы ссылка внутри активного li меняла цвет?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на li, ссылка внутри него меняла цвет на белый и возвращалась к изначальному черному цвету, когда происходит клик на другой li? У меня ссылка активного li остается черного цвета

Сам сайт http://cb95142.tmweb.ru/

Весь код https://jsfiddle.net/mdgtochb/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
/*Меняет цвет нажатого li */


$('.sidebar-menu li').click(function(event) {
        $(this).toggleClass('click');
        $(".sidebar-menu li").not(this).removeClass("click");
    });
```

```css
.facilities .click {
  background-color: #ff5722;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
                            <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                                <li id="parking"><a href="#">Spacious parking area</a></li>
                                <li id="comfortable"><a href="#">Comfortable spaces</a></li>
                                <li id="cozy"><a href="#">Cozy cafe</a></li>
                                <li id="playground"><a href="#">Child playground</a></li>
                                <li id="outdoor"><a href="#">Outdoor spaces</a></li>
                            </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

js можно чуть короче:

```
  $('.sidebar-menu li').click(function(event) {
            $(".sidebar-menu li").removeClass("click");
            $(this).addClass('click');            
     });
```

добавить в css:

```
.facilities .click a {
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: Сработало, НО на разрешении менее 1200px  при клики на любую другую область вне меню, остается висеть оранжевый фон на ссылке, можете посмотреть, залили актиуальную версию http://cb95142.tmweb.ru/

Comment: @Toppy  я же написал добавить в css, а не заменить. Вот у вас должны быть эти две записи в style.css - .facilities .click a {  
  color: #fff !important;
}
.facilities .click {
  background-color: #ff5722;  
}